# How to decrypt data from Encrypt module

Tags: 7

One of my webform component is using [Webform Encrypt](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_encrypt). The Encrypt feature is from [Encrypt](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt) and [Key](https://www.drupal.org/project/key) modules. I set the key and encrypt as following. Everything is working fine in the submission data, but how can I decrypt the encrypted data if I send the data to someone? I have been searching this for days with no solution. Some online AES calculator has "IV" input and I don't know where to get that information.

Key:
type type: AES Encryption
key size: 256
key provider: file
file location: something/encrypt_key.key with based64-encoded

Encrypt:
General setting: enabled
Encryption Method: Mcrypt AES (CBC mode)
Key Provider: Key module(It's the key I made from Key module)

**--- update question --- Apr 14th 12:24pm

How the person decrypt the data when I sent the encrypted data to him/her?**

Comment: It's encryption. They need to use the same libraries and have access to the secret keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `decrypt()` function as seen in [`_webform_encrypt_decrypt_nested_values`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform_encrypt/tree/webform_encrypt.module#n140):

```
/**
 * Helper function to recursively decrypt values in a webform structure.
 */
function _webform_encrypt_decrypt_nested_values(&$element, $key = '#default_value', $restrict = array()) {
  // Determine if we are checking access.
  $access = empty($restrict) ? TRUE : user_access('view encrypted values', $restrict['account']);

  // Loop through each item and decrypt the value.
  foreach (element_children($element) as $name) {
    $component = &$element[$name];
    if (!empty($component['#webform_component']['extra']['encrypt'])) {
      if (is_array($component[$key])) {
        foreach ($component[$key] as &$value) {
          $value = $access ? decrypt($value, array('base64' => TRUE)) : t('[Value Encrypted]');
        }
      }
      else {
        $component[$key] = $access ? decrypt($component[$key], array('base64' => TRUE)) : t('[Value Encrypted]');
      }
    }

    // Recurse if the current item has children.
    _webform_encrypt_decrypt_nested_values($component, $key, $restrict);
  }
}
```

So in your own code you want to call something like `decrypt($value, array('base64' => TRUE))` where `$value` is (saved) encrypted webform submission data.